# Where should I call a web service in iOS like viewdidload or didappear

Tags: ios, objective-c

Where should I call web service in iOS please help me I am new in iOS

Thanks

Comment: Actually my UI freeze coz I I am calling web service and data from local db so I want my UI not to freez

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you want to call the web service every time when view display on screen that call it in ViewWillAppear. And if you want to call the web service only once in entire life cycle of the viewController than call it in ViewDidLoad.